# Automatically switch to new help frame

Tags: frames, help

Now that emacs supports frames in terminal mode, I'm finding that the help commands open in a new frame. Is there a way to automatically switch to the new frame after it is created? I have seen the answer that forces the help buffers to open in the current frame, but since I have defined a special look for the help frames, I like that it creates them in a new frame. I would like to switch to it automatically. What is more annoying is that `C-x 5 o` doesn't even take me there but goes to `*Messages*` first. It took me a long time to figure out why I couldn't see the help information.

Comment: I think you're not giving enough details to give an answer.   Please specify *exactly* how you setup your Emacs such that the helkp command open in a new frame.  Also I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "frame" since you say "Now that Emacs supports frames in terminal mode" whereas I don't think there's been much change w.r.t frames in terminal mode since Emacs-21.

Comment: using package https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle you can create various behavior rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in .emacs:

```
(setq help-window-select t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun foo () (let ((pop-up-frames  t)) (pop-to-buffer "*Help*")))

(add-hook 'help-mode-hook 'foo)
```